# Move One activity to Another Activity using function

Tags: android

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        user_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        submit_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);

        submit_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Sender s = new Sender(v.getContext(),urlAddress,user_name,password);
                s.execute();

                cxt = getApplicationContext();
            }
        });
    }

    public void GoUserActivity(){
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,com.example.prakash.cinihive.UserActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Sender.java

package com.example.prakash.cinihive;

```
public class Sender extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
    Context c;
    String urlAddress;
    EditText user_name,password;

    String UserName,Password;

    ProgressDialog pd;

    MainActivity main = new MainActivity();

    public Sender(Context c, String urlAddress, EditText user_name, EditText password) {
        this.c = c;
        this.urlAddress = urlAddress;
        this.user_name = user_name;
        this.password = password;

        UserName = user_name.getText().toString();
        Password = password.getText().toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd = new ProgressDialog(c);
        pd.setTitle("send");
        pd.setMessage("Sending..Please wait");
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        return this.send();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);
        pd.dismiss();

        if(response !=null){
            //Toast.makeText(c,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Log.d("Response",response);
            if(response.equals("false")){
                Toast.makeText(c,"Invalid Credentials",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{

                main.GoUserActivity();
                //Toast.makeText(c,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            user_name.setText("");
            password.setText("");


        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(c,"Un succesfullll",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public  String send(){
        HttpURLConnection con = Connector.connect(urlAddress);

        //Toast.makeText(c,con.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(con==null){
            Toast.makeText(c,"Connection Null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return null;
        }

        try{
            // Log.d("Connection status","Connection not null");
            OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();

            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));
            bw.write(new DataPack(UserName,Password).Packdata());

            bw.flush();
            bw.close();
            os.close();

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

            Log.d("MYINT","Response Id :"+responseCode);

            if(responseCode==con.HTTP_OK){
                Log.d("Response code","Response code success");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                String line;

                while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                    response.append(line);
                }

                br.close();

                return response.toString();
            }else{
                Log.d("Response code","Failure");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is my code My problem was Intent Statement Not working in GoUserActivity funtion 
    At the same time  Intent Statement Working well in OnCreate function.
When I try to run  inside GoUserActivity,it will raise the runtime error(NullPoniterException "Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,com.example.prakash.cinihive.UserActivity.class);")

Comment: Among other many terrible things you do, you cannot call new MainActivity(). You should throw this out and rewrite it. What do you actually want to do? What is your use case?

Comment: indeed, as said above, there are a lot of terrible things here. Can you explain in simple words what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My workflow: get username and password from android user and check my web server user databse,if login success go another activity otherwise display message "invalid credentials"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find things work better if you move your AsyncTask inside MainActivity as an inner class.  You'll be able to call GoUserActivity() without having to new another instance of MainActivity, which you should never do.